# Web service Automation testing using Http client

Tags: java, httpclient

```
Javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed:
```

I am trying to automate webserivce using Java Http client for invoking the services and getting this exception.The endpoint url which I am trying to invoke has https. can anyone help to resolve ths issue

Comment: Please refer the previous answers:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9619030/resolving-javax-net-ssl-sslhandshakeexception-sun-security-validator-validatore

Comment: You should add certificates for whatever server url it is failing